Why is my ngrx parameter showing an error?
I have the following service that signs up a user:
public signup = (user:UserModel) => {
    console.log('UserService.user', user)

    return this.httpClient.post<{user:UserModel}>(this.url, {user}).pipe(
      tap(user => {
        console.log('UserService.user tap', user)
        this.store.dispatch(StoreUser({user}))
      })
   )
 }

I am trying to dispatch the user received from the backend to the StoreUser action but I am getting an error. The user parameter in this line this.store.dispatch(StoreUser({user}) has a red line indicating an error. The error which appears to be a type error is shown below:

Type '{ user: UserModel; }' is missing the following properties from type 'UserModel': firstName, lastName, password, email, tokents(2739)
user.actions.ts(6, 13): The expected type comes from property 'user' which is declared here on type '{ user: UserModel; }'
(property) user: UserModel

This is the UserModel class:
export class UserModel {
    public firstName:string = '';
    public lastName:string = '';
    public password:string = '';
    public email:string = '';
    public token:string = '';
}

This is the action:
import { createAction, props } from "@ngrx/store";
import { UserModel } from "./user.model";

export const StoreUser = createAction(
    '[Store user] Store user',
    props<{ user:UserModel }>()
  );


public signin = (user:UserModel) => {
return this.httpClient.put<UserModel>(this.url, {user}).pipe(
  tap(user => {
    console.log('UserService.user tap: ', user)
    this.store.dispatch(StoreUser({user: user}))
  }),
  catchError(error => {
    console.log('error', error)
    this.toastr.warning(error.error, '');
    throw error;
  })    
)

}
Model:
export class UserModel {
    public firstName?:string;
    public lastName?:string;
    public password?:string;
    public email?:string;
    public token?:string;
}

Action:
export const StoreUser = createAction(
'[Store user] Store user',
props<{ user:UserModel}>()

);

I guess that user in tap has type of { user: UserModel }.
If so, then it is either tap(({ user }) => ...) (with curly braces around user) or something like this:
tap(response => {
  const user = response.user
  console.log('UserService.user tap', user)
  this.store.dispatch(StoreUser({user}))
})


Either the solution that Tortila provided works for me or simply removing the curly braces around user property when you call the action to get rid of the type mismatch.
The Action expects type { user: Model} since you typed the post method to return exactly that type you get the mismatch because you wrap user into additional {} therefore changing the type.
expected: {user: UserModel}
provided by you: {{user: UserModel}}
...
    return this.httpClient.post<{ user: UserModel }>(this.url, {user}).pipe(
      tap((user) => {
        console.log('UserService.user tap', user)
        this.store.dispatch(storeUserAction(user))
      })
    )

